# subsequences of sin(n)

Tags: real-analysis

It is well known that $( \sin(n) )_{n\ge 1}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$.  Often one falls in exercise calculation on subsequences of this one: like $\sin(n^2)$ for example; let us generalize right away to $\sin(n^\alpha)$ for $\alpha>0$. These sequences should be dense as well, but that is not clear right away.

For $\sin(n^2)$ for example, Weyl's argument would require to show that  $\sum_{k=1}^n \exp( i k^2 m)  = o(n)$ which is not clear to me, since I cannot calculate explicitly this sum. Is there some nice trick to handle the density of $\sin(n^\alpha)$  ?

Comment: Is $\alpha$ an integer or real?

Comment: Well, already integer $\alpha$' s seem an interesting subject. All $\alpha>0$ are even more sexy. It seems that $\sin(n^n)$ s solved (on JSTOR that I cannot read, https://www.jstor.org/stable/43678733). Maybe there is literature in that paper

Comment: should I add a number-theory flag?

Comment: It should be $\exp (ik^2m)$, no $2\pi$ factor. For $\alpha > 1$ (maybe also for $\alpha < 1$) the method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637667/show-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac1n-sum-limits-k-0n-1eik2-0) should work, for $0 < \alpha < 1$ the Euler-Maclaurin formula should help.

Comment: [Here is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325386/can-we-extend-the-proof-of-density-of-sinn-to-sinn2) a related question.

Answer (score 1):

Some answers, I eventually found.

In this book, https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/%7Ejosefdick/preprints/KuipersNied_book.pdf we have a nice Theorem 3.2 stating that for any polynomial with real coefficients and at least one irrational coefficient, p(n) is unif. distributed mod 1.  In my setting, $\sin(n^2) =\sin(\pi n^2/\pi)$ the polynomial p(n) = n^2/\pi$ satisfies the criterion.

Another situation is $\sin(n^n)$ that seems to be treated  here https://www.jstor.org/stable/43678733.